# Galois field computations on Linux

Tags: linux, math, polynomial-math

Is there any software available on Linux for Galois field calculus?

Comment: this question should be migrated to [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com). Also, [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222/97) at physics.SE might provide some useful hints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little bit of searching, and found a couple of options:

**[Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)**

> Sage can be used to study elementary and advanced, pure and applied mathematics. This includes a huge range of mathematics, including basic algebra, calculus, elementary to very advanced number theory, cryptography, numerical computation, commutative algebra, group theory, combinatorics, graph theory, exact linear algebra and much more.

[Here's](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/tour_polynomial.html) part of the tutorial on polynomials.

---

**[Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)**

> A high-level language, primarily intended for numerical computations. It provides a convenient command line interface for solving linear and nonlinear problems numerically, and for performing other numerical experiments using a language that is mostly compatible with Matlab.

---

**[Singular](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/)**

> A computer algebra system for polynomial computations, with special emphasis on commutative and non-commutative algebra, algebraic geometry, and singularity theory.

Note that I have not used the software listed above, and am merely trying to provide some helpful links. Asking this question on the [Mathematics SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com/) will likely provide some more in-depth answers. Hope this helps.